# gatsby plugin sass @debug logs unreadable in terminal

Tags: debugging, sass, gatsby

i'm using "gatsby-plugin-sass", (which is basically node-sass) in my project. it's working fine, but when i use the sass "@debug" directive i get a flash of the debug log in my terminal window and then it's gone before i can even read it. is there a place where i can configure node sass to force the debug log to stay in the output of my terminal long enough to read it? it's useless as it is. i've tried a search for gatsby plugin sass options, but nothing addresses my issue. is there a file i can open to see what was logged?

i'm on a mac book pro, using webStorm.

Comment: not a solution to your question, but if you use `@error` instead of `@debug` does it at least throw so you can read the debug message?

Comment: @DerekNguyen, Yes, it does give my what I was trying to log. That's better than nothing. Thanks!